# Including Lemmas into Theorems

Tags: theorems

I want to include some lemmas inside the proof of a theorem in a way that makes clear that those lemmas are part of the proof and not independent (e.g. smaller size of letters etc). Are there any ways to do this?

Comment: the traditional way is to not issue the "qed" marker until the end of the proof.